# How we can partition $a_1, a_2, a_3, ... a_n$ in two sequence X and Y such that their sum of differences be minimum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, integer-partitions

I couldn't write any algorithm that can do this in good order for $a_i < 100$ and $n < 2000$ :(

how we can partition $a_1, a_2, a_3, ... a_n$ in two sequence X and Y such that $|X_1 - X_2| + |X_2 - X_3| + ... + |X_{m - 1} + X_m| + |Y_1 - Y_2| + |Y_2 - Y_3| + ... + |Y_{t - 1} + Y_t|$ being minimum?

Please help me please
sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Here is a naive approach, that should not be too bad: sort the $a_i$, then the smaller element goes to $X$, the next to $Y$, the following to $X$, and so on.

Comment: @Mariuslp But can you prove that this is the optimal solution? That's more interesting I guess.

Comment: Is there some limit on the number of terms in each sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You can see that whatever the final sequences are, it is optimal only if both are in ascending or descending order. It is kinda easy to show that. Let $X_l, X_m,X_n$ be the terms of any of the final two sequences in order. It can be seen that the value when they are out of order will be greater than when they are in order.

Now once they are in order we can see that the $|X_1 - X_2| + |X_2 - X_3| + ... + |X_{m - 1} + X_m| + |Y_1 - Y_2| + |Y_2 - Y_3| + ... + |Y_{t - 1} + Y_t|$ can be replaced by $|X_m - X_1| + |Y_t - Y_1|$ i.e. the quantity depends only on the final and first terms in each sequence.

Now how do we get the maximum sum out of the two series. By splitting the initial sorted sequence along the largest gap. So let  $|Z_1 - Z_2| , |Z_2 - Z_3| , ... , |Z_{k - 1} + Z_k|$ be the gaps on the undivided sorted sequence. Find out which of the gaps is the largest . Then create the two sequences such that that gap vanishes.

Comment: "This can ideally be achieved by having no terms in the second sequence." I disagree, if all elements are in $X$, then the sum is equal to $a_{max} - a_{min}$. However, splitting where the difference between $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ is maximal gives better results: look for instance at the sequence $1, 2, 3, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107$. Putting everything in $X$ yields a sum of $106$, but with $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $Y = \{103, 104, 105, 106, 107\}$ the sum plunges to $6$.

Comment: Yep you are right. I hope the first part to my answer is correct.

Comment: I have changed the answer. Hope it is now correct.

Comment: It also seems to me that elements must be in arithmetic progression, but I don't have the time (nor idea) to prove it. If it is true, then you can prove that for optimality necessarily $Y_1 > X_m$, and thus that splitting at the maximum difference will be optimal.

Comment: @Mariuslp Not arithmetic progression, sorry, I made a mistake there. They need to be in ascending or descending order. They need to be ordered.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I actually read the way you intended